# Delete one value from a jquery cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Im saving product ID-s in a jquery cookie, named `kedvenc_termek_cookie`.

When I look at this cookie in the console, I get the id-s, that are in the cookie, like: 70,12,99,105,44

How can I delete one id from this cookie?

```
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
    if ($.cookie("kedvenc_termek_cookie"))
    {
        var favorite_items_id = $.cookie("kedvenc_termek_cookie");
        $( "#favorite_items" ).load( "files/kedvencek.php?id="+favorite_items_id, function() {
            $('.delete_kedvenc_span').click(function(e)
            {
                var KedvencID = $(this).attr("id");
                alert(KedvencID);
            });
        });
    }
});



<?php
session_start();
if (file_exists("connect.php")) {include_once("connect.php");}
if (file_exists("functions.php")) {include_once("functions.php");}
$id = explode(';', $_GET["id"]);
foreach( $id AS $i)
{
    $lista[] = intval($i);
}
$list = implode(',' , $lista );
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT termek_id, termek_nev, termek_seo, termek_rovid FROM termek WHERE termek_status = 1 AND termek_id in ($list) ORDER BY termek_nev ASC";
$get_main_items = mysqli_query($kapcs, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($kapcs));
if(mysqli_num_rows($get_main_items) > 0 )
{
    while($i = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_main_items))
    {
        ?>
        <div class="kedvenc_termek_div">
            <h4 class="kedvenc_title pull-left ">
                <a class="kedvenc_title_link" href="<?php echo $host; ?>/termek/<?php echo html($i['termek_id']); ?>/<?php echo html($i['termek_seo']); ?>" title="<?php echo html($i['termek_nev']); ?>"><?php echo html($i['termek_nev']); ?></a>
            </h4>
            <span class="pull-right delete_kedvenc_span" id="<?php echo html($i['termek_id']); ?>" title="Törlés a kedvencek közül">
                <i class="fa fa-minus-circle delete_kedvenc" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </span>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <p class="kedvenc_desc"><?php echo html($i['termek_rovid']); ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
die();
?>
```

Comment: If the IDs are a string, you could split the string to get an array, remove the items that you don't want from the array, convert the array back to string and write the cookie back.

Comment: Holy sh...And how? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var cookie = $.cookie("kedvenc_termek_cookie");
var ids = cookie.split(',')

var index = ids.indexOf(KedvencID);
if (index !== -1){
    ids.splice(index, 1);
    cookie = ids.join();
}

$.cookie("kedvenc_termek_cookie", cookie);
```

It will get the cookie, split it into an array, remove specified element, covert array back to string separated with commas and update cookie.

Comment: This deletes all the text from the cookie. The cookie is still in the browser, but its empty.

Comment: I updated answer. There was a problem when id was not found in array.

Comment: Now it works, and i have to modify this line:  var ids = cookie.split(';')

The separator must be a ;, not a ,

Thank you!

Comment: Also, there was another problem to. When i was saving the product as favorit, the id separator was something other, like ;